# How to configure a Pi model A for OTG usage (as a USB slave)

Tags: usb, pi-a

Seeing as how the model A supports OTG mode via the hardware (both the CPU and USB controller were designed for it)

> The USB host port inside the Pi is an On-The-Go (OTG) host as the
>   application processor powering the Pi, BCM2835, was originally
>   intended to be used in the mobile market: i.e. as the single USB port
>   on a phone for connection to a PC, or to a single device

Source

I would like to ask how to access and use this functionality

specifically I want to get the Pi to act like a USB flash drive and expose a partition of the SD card via that interface. I intend to use this in my car instead of a USB flash drive, and have the Pi connect to wifi and sync the contents of the drive periodically (such that I do not have to physically remove the flash drive in order to update the content that the car sees). If there are other devices that can do this, I would be interested in them as well (Phones wouldn't work because they need to be turned on via a physical button instead of simply turning on when power is provided).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are no software drivers for USB OTG and thus it can't be used.

Comment: Seems kind of odd to create hardware that supports something and then not implement the proper drivers for it... especially since similar drivers are used for mobile phones already (perhaps an android on the Pi would have the drivers..)